# Extensions of Height-Preserving Isomorphisms in Ulm's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I am working through the proof of Ulm's Theorem in Kaplansky's book ``Infinite Abelian Groups." Ulm's theorem states that two countable reduced abelian $p$-groups $G,H$ with the same Ulm invariants are isomorphic. Kaplansky's particular proof of Ulm's theorem is important because it is often used, word-for-word, to prove similar classification theorems for other kinds of structures. The key step in this proof is to extend a given height-preserving isomorphism to another height-preserving isomorphism.

The part I'm confused about has nothing to do with the Ulm invariants or the fact that these groups are reduced, so please excuse me if I don't define these notions. However, central to the proof is the notion of height. We can define, inductively, $G_0 = G$, $G_{\alpha + 1} = pG_{\alpha}$, and $G_{\alpha}$ for limit $\alpha$ is defined in the obvious way by taking intersections. For $x \in G$, we define the height of $x$, denoted $h(x)$, to be $\infty$ if $x=0$ and $\alpha$ if $x \in G_{\alpha}$ but not $G_{\alpha + 1}$. It can be easily shown that if $h(x) \neq h(y)$ then $h(x+y) =$ min $(h(x),h(y))$ and  if $h(x) = h(y)$ then $h(x+y) \geq h(x)$.

The proof proceeds in stages. At stage $n$, we start with a height-preserving isomorphism $V:S \rightarrow T$ between finite subgroups $S,T$ of $G,H$ respectively. We then take an arbitrary element $x$ of $G$ and extend $V$ to include $x$ in its domain. We are allowed to assume that i) $x \not \in S$ but $px \in S$, ii) $x$ is proper with respect to $S$, meaning that $h(x) \geq h(x+s)$ for all $s \in S$, and iii) $h(px) \geq h(p(x+s))$ for all $s \in S$. We then find an element $w \in H$ such that $w \not \in T$, $pw = V(px)$, $h(w) = h(x)$, and $w$ is proper with respect to $T$. Extending $V$ in the obvious way we get a map $V': \langle S,x \rangle \rightarrow \langle T,w \rangle$, which should still be an isomorphism and height-preserving.

**My question is: Why is $V'$ height-preserving?** Note that all heights are supposed to be calculated with respect to the larger groups $G,H$.

Now, an arbitrary element of $\langle S,x \rangle$ is of the form $s \pm nx$. Since for any $x$, $h(x) = h(-x)$, it suffices to show that $V'$ preserves the height of an element of the form $s+nx$. Moreover since $px \in S$ we may assume $n < p$. That is, we want to show that

$$ h(nx+s) = h(nw + V(s)).$$

So far, I have only been able to show that $h(x+s) = h(w+V(s))$, which follows since $h(x+s) =$ min $(h(x), h(s))$ by the fact that $x$ is proper with respect to $S$. There is also a proof of Ulm's theorem in Fuchs' ``Infinite Abelian Groups", which seems to claim that this fact is enough to conclude that $V'$ is height-preserving. I don't understand this at all; there doesn't seem to be any clear connection between $h(nx+s)$ and $h(x+s)$.  Even ignoring this advice, I am pretty stuck since height does not seem to be well-behaved with respect to addition.

Comment: Notice that $h(x+s)$ is the minimum of $h(x)$ and $h(s)$. (p28 of Kaplansky.) What is the height of $2x+s$ (assuming $p$ is odd, as we only consider $n<p$)? Write $s=2s'$, and then $h(2x+s)=h(2(x+s'))=\min(h(x),h(s'))$, and it should be clear from here, unless I've done something silly.

Comment: First, I'm not sure why we can write s = 2s'; a priori, it seems there may be many elements of $S$ not divisible by 2. Also, it seems you are assuming that $h(2(x+s')) = h(x+s').$ Why is this true? In general, for an element $y$, I know that $h(y +y) \geq y$, but I don't see a way to conclude that $h(2y)=y$. I have thought that perhaps $h(ny) = y$ whenever $n$ is not a multiple of $p$, but have never succeeded in showing this.

Comment: Actually, I have shown that for arbitrary $y$, and $p>2$, that $h(2y) = y$. First, we show that for any element $y$ that $h(ny) \geq y$. A simply proof by induction suffices to do this. Next, we note that $h((p+1)y) = h(y+py) = $ min$(h(y), h(py)) = h(y)$, which follows since $h(py) > h(y)$. Finally, we then note that $h(y) = h((p+1)y) = h(2qy) \geq h(2y) \geq h(y)$ so $h(y) = h(2y)$. 

However, in order to generalize your argument, we would still need to show that $h(ny) = h(y)$ for $2<n <p$. The argument I have for $n=2$ does not seem to lift to larger $n$.

Comment: If you are in a $p$-group, then for $n$ prime to $p$, $x$ and $nx$ generate the same cyclic subgroup of $G$. So any cyclic subgroup containing one contains the other? (It also shows why you can always take $n$th roots for $n$ prime to $p$.)

Comment: It might be helpful to consider this alternative characterization of height: $x\in G$ has height $a$ if the cyclic subgroup $C$ of largest size containing $x$ satisfies $|C:\langle x\rangle|=p^a$.

Comment: Okay, so, if I'm understanding you correctly, this would show that for $x$ and $nx$, for $n<p$, they have the same cyclic subgroup $C$ of largest size containing them, (since any cyclic subgroup containing one contains the other), so in particular, they will have the same height? Please forgive me, it has been too many years since my last group theory course. 

This is a very interesting characterization of height, which might be very helpful. Can you direct me to a resource for this?

I remain unclear as to why we might be able to write $s = 2s'$, but this definitely feels like progress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142786/discussion-between-david-a-craven-and-rachael-alvir).

Comment: To anyone that might come back to this question, and for the sake of completion, here is the proof that $h(nx) = h(x)$ for all $n$ prime to $p$ and $x \in G$, which works even if the height is not a finite number $a$. Note first that $h(nx) \geq h(x)$ which can be shown easily by induction. Then note that for $n$ prime to $p$, $\langle x \rangle = \langle nx \rangle$ so $x = knx$ for some $k$. Therefore $h(x) = h(knx) \geq h(nx)$.